# Some Kotlin libraries attached to this project were read by a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update Kotlin Plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am facing an error:

> Some Kotlin libraries attached to this project were read by a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update Kotlin Plugin

I just created an application and started facing this error:
[image]

The Kotlin plugin shows the following:

[image]

I tried to change ext.kotlin_version:
[image]

My build.gradle:

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle(app):

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yousufjamil.myj"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update almost everything, I believe.

currently for Gradle we have
`com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1`

coming to Kotlin, the current version is `1.6.21`

repository `jcenter()` is deprecated and has been replaced by `mavenCentral()`

If you try to use `jcenter()` it will give a warning

> JCenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates: newer library versions may be available elsewhere

Also, check if there are any updates available for Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried doing your steps and it showed: Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.3.3. Current version is 6.5.

Comment: I have tried to fix it but it shows that I will need to install a newer version of Android Studio. By the way, thanks for your help.

Comment: In my case, I've tried everything, and the final solution is to upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 5):

Earlier I had the same error on Android Studio. If by changing the *kotlin-version* and *gradle-version* in the *build.gradle* file does not fixes the error. It might be because you have an older version and need to update the Android Studio [File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates -> ' then Change to the latest stable version']. Later during the installation process, you would see the option to upgrade the *gradle* where you can choose the latest version. It worked for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already solved the problem by updating android studio.

Answer (score 2):

1- update the android studio by clicking the tab named help and then click "check for update" and then let the android studio be updated.
2 - restart the android studio if the error is resolved then it's well and good if not, then click on the tab "New", click on "New project" and then select project, and check the box highlighted here in the below picture.
[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Pgn.png)

this worked for me

Comment: I've already worked out the solution, but still thanks.

Answer (score 2):

update android studio to the lastest version

Answer (score 0):

only need to del these
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).